# How do I get my Inno Setup custom icon to consistently display in Windows like it does in programs not included in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, icons, inno-setup

I have created several setup aka installer exe files using Inno Setup. When I have done my testing I have created my installer files on my Desktop. Most of my icons display properly but it appears a bit sporadic when displaying the icon on the setup installer file. When I use a program not included in Windows to open a folder that contains the setup installer files it consistently displays the icons. However when I do the same thing using a program included in Windows they do not consistently display. The images below are two examples.

[image]

The window on the left is Inno Setup. You can see that all the icons display as expected. I also tried this with another program that I have since deleted and the three icons displayed. The window on the right is WordPad. Only one of the icons displays for the Basic Cubic Puzzles Setup file.

[image]

This image shows the three setup files on my desktop. As you see none of them show the custom icons that consistently appear in programs that are not included in Windows.

Here is my code in my iss file.

```
#define MyIconFile "ThePathForMyCustomIcon"

[Setup]

SetupIconFile={#MyIconFile}   

[Icons]

Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon; IconFilename: "{#MyIconFile}"
```

Is there a Inno Setup parameter that I can set specifically for Windows to get my custom icon to consistently display when I use programs within Windows?

This is the first time I have used Windows in almost ten years. I purchased a Windows 10 touchscreen laptop not quite two weeks ago. My last experience with Windows was with XP. I have already done a Disk Cleanup before my last attempt at recreating my setup files. I'm not sure what the next step is.

Comment: I have never experienced such issue - even today with Windows 10 and WordPad I can see my proper Icon for my setup files. Perhaps you have kind of Icon Cache stored that displays generic icons? Or maybe you Icon Files contain proper images only for some resolutions?

Comment: @RobeN, thanks for your quick response. How do I locate the icon cache? I assume you are talking about in Windows. I did not see anything in the Inno Setup that stated a size limit for icon dimensions. What icon sizes do you use? My icon files are 167x167.

Comment: @RobeN, I did a web search and found a link where I was able to find out that the icon cache was a single file. I deleted it and restarted my laptop. The one icon that showed up in WordPad now shows up on the desktop. It looks like I may need to redo the icons for the other two. If you post your suggestion about the Icon cache as an answer I will uncheck it. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It was a caching problem. I found a link on how to rebuild the icon cache for Windows 10. When I rebooted my laptop all of my icons appeared. I'm still learning Windows and only use it when I have to for testing.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I asked RobeN to answer it because he suggested the icon cache first. I want to give him credit for posting an answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have never experienced such issue - even today with Windows 10 and WordPad I can see my proper Icon for my setup files.

I suspect you encounter Icon Cache issue which stores generic icons that were somehow cached earlier for Inno Setup generic installers.

You can try to clear Windows Icon Cache - please note that way you do it differs for Windows Vista/7 and for Windows 8/10. 
One approach is described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/).